# I messed up my neighbors wifi

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, clone

I messed up my neighbors Wifi. My neighbors let me use their Wifi, and it wasn't working right, and I read something that said to clone your MAC address.

I typed in the IP address on Chrome and was on the Belkin site (I knew the password so I could get in). I cloned the MAC address to my computer, and now only my computer and the neighbors computer which is connected to the Ethernet can connect.

Is there a way of fixing this, maybe if I went to his house and went onto his computer and cloned his MAC address?

Comment: What might be easier is if you just reset the router.  This will restore the default configuration.

Answer (score 11):

There is. Go back to the place where you cloned the MAC address and restore the default.

Some background:

A MAC address is a **unique** identifier. Much like a serial number it is set by the manufacturer. When identifying a piece of a local network this unique 48 bits value will be used.

You just cloned (copied) it and it is no longer unique, thus breaking things.

Cloning/copying the MAC is only needed if:

1. You are trying to break things.
2. Or you are trying to break into some place pretending to be some other computer (done while the other computer is turned off).
3. Or when you get locked out due to MAC filtering. (Which provides as much security as a locked door with the key still in the door. In other words: none)
4. Or, in ancient times, with some cable providers which checked the very easily fakeable MAC to see if that was really you. I suspect that whatever you read was to work around this.